# clearing cookies on modal window

Tags: trigger.io

I am using forge.tabs.openWithOptions to go through the OAuth2 authentication and would like to provide an option for a user to logout and login as a different user without having to uninstall the application completely. However it seems like Trigger.io saves the cookies.
Is there any way to clear the cookies so that the user can re-login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have raised a ticket for this in our feature backlog and will report back when it is complete - currently there is no way to directly clear the cookies in a modal view opened with forge.tabs.openWithOptions

Comment: Are there any update on this one? It's been 5 months about this issue.

Comment: Is it still not possible to clear the cookies inside child browser?